# Python import error. Circular imports

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'm creating a simple flask app. I'm using blueprints to provide views and OpenID for login. I have faced the problem when I try to import created OpenID object to the file with the views interpreter throws an Import Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../ProgList/ProgList.py", line 11, in <module>
    from views_admin import views as views_a
  File "/.../ProgList/views_admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ProgList import open_id
  File "/.../ProgList/ProgList.py", line 11, in <module>
    from views_admin import views as views_a
  ImportError: cannot import name 'views'
```

---

**ProgList.py**

```
# importing VIEWS
from views import views
from views_admin import views as views_a
...
open_id = OpenID(app, 'temp_dir_path')
```

---

**views_admin.py**

```
from ProgList import open_id
...
@views.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@open_id.loginhandler
def login():
```

---

I have been struggling this problem for hours and couldn't find an answer.
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: no, in the .py file _views_admin.py_ a **Blueprint** named _views_ was created

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Could you provide the code that is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ProgList`, you import `views_admin`, in `views_admin`, you import `ProgList`. This cannot be resolved. The typical approach here is to outsource something to a third file which both can safely access without interfering with each other. From the looks of it, you might want to move `open_id` into a different file.

Comment: thank you. I have made an package (with __init__.py and other stuff) and it began to work.