# django models relation to two models before saving

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two apps say app1 and app2 and I have models in it.

```
from app2.models import SecondModel
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    first_field = models.ManyToManyField(SecondModel, blank=True)# or Foreign Key

from app1.models import FirstModel
class SecondModel(models.Model):
    second_field = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
```

When I do this I get import error.

Could not import name 'FirstModel'

Why is this happening ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python import error. Circular imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726699/python-import-error-circular-imports)

Comment: cf http://stackoverflow.com/q/23726699/41316 : you have a circular import, it cannot work.

Comment: And you should question whether you need this bi-directional relationship. SecondModel already gets a relationship to FirstModel by virtue of the ManyToManyField.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I can get second model field if I have id of first model but if I have id of second model then I canot get first model so I used circular relationship

Comment: No. Given an instance of SecondModel, you can do `my_instance.firstmodel_set.all()` to get all the FirstModels it is related to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have a circular import. It's not possible to for both modules to import from each other.

In this case, you don't need to import the models into each app. Remove the imports, and use a string `app_label.ModelName` instead.

```
# app1.models.py
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    first_field = models.ManyToManyField('app2.SecondModel')

# app2.models.py
class SecondModel(models.Model):
    second_field = models.ForeignKey('app1.FirstModel')
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a name conflict here .. you defined the `FirstModel` in your models.py and then defined `FirstModel`, from the code above, this could be the possible problem. Also, the import error generally mean, there is no FirstModel defined from where you are importing it.

However, a more generic way of doing FKs without import is generally

```
class FkModel(models.Model):
    relationship = models.ManyToManyField('appName.modelName')
```

where appName is the app from where you are trying to import the model from, and modelName is the model to which you are trying to create the relationship. This helps where you are trying to do something like this.

Lets say your app name is 'app' and you are trying to create a many to many relationship from 1st model to a 2nd model for which the class is declared after the 1st model e.g.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    first_field = models.ManyToManyField('app.Model1')

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=256)
```

that is just put your appname.modelName inside strings :)

also, you have a flaw in your `ManyToManyField()` declaration i.e. you don't need to define blank in Many to Many. The way db's work under the hood is, they create a 3rd database table just to store many to many relationships.

hope it helps

//mouse.